# Changing icon and text sizes (and toggling) for visually handicapped

Tags: 14.04, unity, display, display-resolution, zooming

I need to temporarily make everything larger: icons, text, etc. while I cope with a temporary visual problem. Is there an easy way to toggle between normal resolution and "large-print", if you will? (I don't see an easy way to adjust things for the visually handicapped, whether temporary or permanent.)

**EDIT-1**: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 with Unity desktop.

**EDIT-2**: I am asking not for a direct zoom or magnification where everying is increased at once and the desktop goes "off-screen" so that you have to move it around to see everything -- although *come to think of it*, it would be nice to know that, too, as that has its uses. I would like a way to increase the size of the text underneath the desktop icons and the size of the text in Files (Nautilus?) and possibly the size of the icons in the desktop and in files. Actually, increasing the size of most things, including window titles, pulldown menu text, etc. would be helpful as I cannot read the menus so well right now.

Answer (score 2):

**PART ONE**

There is a desktop zoom function which is configurable through the compizconfig-settings-manager.

To install, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now, run the following command to start it up or search **ccsm** in your desktop dash instead:

```
ccsm &
```

Under **Accessibility**, make sure the **Enhanced Desktop Zoom** has a tic in the box next to it.

Then, click on the Enhanced Desktop Zoom plugin to configure it.

I have mine set to **Button1** to zoom in (Button1 is left-click on the mouse).

I also have mine set to **Button3** to zoom out (Button3 is right-click on the mouse).

You can also adjust the "zoom factor" and other settings.

---

**PART TWO**

It may also be helpful to know that you can change the text scaling factor.

First, install unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Start up the unity-tweak-tool and click on **"fonts"**.

The **text scaling factor** setting should be down on the right.

This makes the text larger without changing the size of everything else.

---

**PART THREE**

Additionally, under **System Settings > Universal Access** you can toggle the **large text** option.

[image]

[image]

I do not know of a keyboard shortcut for this but I seem to get used to large text and forget that it is on.

**To change the icon size in nautilus and files:**

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the icon size and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> decrease the size of the icons.

---

**PART FOUR**

To view text files, I use `nano` or `vim` the terminal.

The terminal I use is `guake`.

`guake` is a drop down terminal that allows you to change the text size using the following keyboard combo: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the text size and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> decrease the size of the text in the terminal.

Additionally, I edit my `.bashrc` file to enable all color code options to make things easier to see according to color code.

Comment: I hadn't mentioned earlier that I am using Unity on Trusty Tahr. Is this ccsm for Unity or for GNOME?

Comment: @gracious1 ccsm is for unity.

Comment: @gracious1 Also, I have added that you can go to **System Settings > Universal Access** and then you can turn on the **large text** option, although, there is no keyboard shortcut that I know of.